# javascript .split() string with <p> </p> and ¤

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string containing `<p>`, `</p>` and ¤ that I need to split the string with.

I have tried split 3 times and used toString between to be able to use split().
BUT this gives me a problem, because when I use toString it creates commas (,) .. And I have text containing comma so I cant just split on commas in the end.

```
 var obj = $$.KontaktPersoner.Value;

 var kunde_tabel = obj.split('¤');
 var kt_string = kunde_tabel.toString();
 var kt_v2 = kt_string.split('</p>');
 var kt_v2_string = kt_v2.toString();
 var kt_v3 = kt_v2_string.split('<p>');
```

How do I split the array by `<p>`, `</p>` and ¤?

Comment: What's your actual string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj.split(/<p>|<\/p>|¤/)
```

Comment: No problem, but I just wondered how you didn't notice the syntax highlighting after you hit 'post' is all. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = obj.split(/<p>|<\/p>|¤/)
```

Comment: Square brackets in regexes are for characters, not strings. And please don't plagerise other people's answers without giving attribution.